# Script manager not calling with HttpContext

Tags: c#, asp.net

When i use

```
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this.Page, Page.GetType(), "TTTT111", "alert('calling dfdfd from server .....');", true);
```

before or after

```
HttpContext.Current.Response.Clear();
HttpContext.Current.Response.ContentType = strContentType;
HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", string.Format("attachment; filename={0}", strFileName));
HttpContext.Current.Response.OutputStream.Write(ExportDataString, 0, ExportDataString.Length);
HttpContext.Current.ApplicationInstance.CompleteRequest();
HttpContext.Current.Response.OutputStream.Flush();
```

then it does not call scriptmanager.

Answer (score 0):

The `Content-Disposition` will prompt the user to save the content to disk. It doesn't look like you are rendering the page here. Just writing `ExportDataString` to the stream.

What is it you are expecting to happen?